# Java substring() not working as expected

Tags: java

Consider the following code in Java:

```
String str = "a";
System.out.println("Length is :")+str.length(); //Prints "Length is :1"
System.out.println("Substring is :"+str.substring(1); //Prints "Substring is :"
System.out.println("Char at :")+str.charAt(1); //Throws IndexOutofbounds exception as expected
```

I was under the impression that substring() starts from the index specified till the end of the string. Following this rule, shouldn't the `substring()` function above throw an `arrayindexoutofbounds` exception? Why does it print an empty string? The `charAt()` function works as expected i.e it throws an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually correct. According to the String API:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than
>   the length of this String object.

If you make it substring(2), you will see the exception.

Answer (score 1):

everything is fine, you didn't read the javaDoc carefully.

you have only one char string, so index is only `0`, length is 1. In javaDoc,

### `subString()` will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.
```

so your subString() call won't throw exception because the length is `1`, but return empty str.

### `charAt()`:  while the `charAt()` call, will throw ex if:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the {@code index}
                  argument is negative or ***not less than*** the length of this
                  string.
```

that's why you got the ex.